# Eclipse is not responding for few seconds at jsp files

Tags: eclipse

When i open a jsp file from my project, eclipse not responding for 5-10 seconds at first click.  this problem is only encountered in jsp files and it happens often, not always happening.

How can i fix it?

System Specs:
Windows 10
Eclipse jee 2018-12

I tried this at eclipse neon and eclipse jee 2018-12 but nothing changed.

Comment: Eclipse plug-ins are lazy started when they are needed (to minimize Eclipse startup time and memory). Have you installed an additional plug-in that has something to do with JSP/HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: [1] One thing that is easy to try is to turn off all validators: **Window > Preferences > Validation >** check **Suspend all validators**. If the problem persists you know that it is not caused by validators, and vice versa. [2] Would it be possible for you to list the source of one of the JSPs that has the problem?

Comment: @howlger i didnt installed plug-ins. just used default eclipse j2e

Comment: @skomisa I think it works for me. Still i didnt get any not responding problem. Thanks

Comment: @SemihKoyu To collect data next time it occurs, enable _Window > Preferences: General > UI Responsiveness Monitoring_ (and if you want to send the data to Eclipse also _General > Error Reporting_).

Comment: @SemihKoyu If turning off validators solved your problem, could you consider posting an answer to your own question? That would be more helpful to the community than having to read a discussion in the comments for your question.

Answer (score 2):

I turn off validatiors and solved my problem.

The way for turn off validators;

Window > Preferences > Validation > check Suspend all validators